# Form Security & PHP?

Tags: php

I was using something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ids" value="1, 3, 5" />
<input type="hidden" name="cost" value="350" />
```

But I was thinking, somebody could just change the cost to say "3" and pay for it for $3.00.. so I was thinking, would a securer(sp) option be setting these values into sessions when they load page, like so:

```
<?
unset($_SESSION['baskettotal']);
unset($_SESSION['basketids']);
$_SESSION['baskettotal'] = $grand;
$_SESSION['basketids'] = implode(", ", $ids);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?=md5('stackoverflow'.$_SESSION['baskettotal'].$_SESSION['basketids']);?>" />
<?
if (($_POST['hash']) != (md5('stackoverflow'.$_SESSION['baskettotal'].$_SESSION['basketids']))){
    echo "error";
    die();
}
?>
```

Is this a good way of doing it? As they cannot edit the sessions, it's defined by whats in their basket, as opposed to storing it in hidden input fields which they could easily manipulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed correct, this is a good method of doing this.

1) Create a session that contains the hash of all the values from that form.

2) When the form is submitted, calculate the hash of the  values from the form and compare them against the one in the SESSION var. If they are the same, the user didn't change anything... if they differ, obviously the user changed something.

Just to clarify, the user cannot change any of the SESSION variables, however if you stored this in a cookie for example, the user could potentially edit the hash via that cookie (since it is stored client side, as opposed to server side with sessions).

An example might be:

```
$_SESSION['form_data'] = md5("randomsalt123".$formValue1.$formValue2);
```

and when the user submits the form:

```
if($_SESSION['form_data'] == md5('randomsalt123'.$_POST['form_value_1'].$_POST['form_value_2'])){
 // valid submission

} else {
 // invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I was thinking of salting the ids and price in a hash, for example have it calculate $hash = md5($ids.$price); and then put that in a hidden post value, and when it posts, it creates the same salted hash with the SESSION information and checks it against the posted information.

Comment: What you want to do is (($_POST['hash']) != (md5('stackoverflow'.$_POST['baskettotal'].$_POST['basketids']))) . You want to look at the newly POSTED data and compare it against the old hash.

Comment: Thats basically the same as using SESSION, the only difference with SESSIONs is that they cannot edit the HTML.. using POST and putting the data into input fields, they can edit the HTML, thus edit whats being posted. Doing it with SESSIONS and only POSTING a hash is making it all done server-side and behind the scenes, so the only value they can edit is the hash, which when posted, has to meet the hash on the POSTED side with the SESSIONs salted into it...?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to change the session variables as well.  I would store the cost in a database, which the user cannot change, then either check $_POST['cost'] to make sure it matches what is in the database or do away with the hidden field altogether.

If you do not want to use a db you could store it in a file.

Comment: Care to comment on just how one might change session variables?

Comment: You might be getting them confused with cookies... SESSION data is stored server side.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/add-n-edit-cookies/ <-- There is an addon for firefox that allows you to edit session and cookie variables.

Comment: Hmm, I guess everyone says it is stored server side... Oh well, I always make it a good habbit to never trust session variables for anything important (such as financial info). But I guess it should theoretically be safe.

Comment: Yes, you can edit the session id, however you can't actually edit the session variables. That session ID is strictly to lookup against the server. Once the server identifies who's session you want (based on that session ID you see in the cookie), you can then access them through $_SESSION['var'] etc.

Comment: @Mike you can't, but the server can ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What about storing them in the session and not displaying them in the form? (Or just ignore them when you are doing your calculations).

Comment: @Kyle And I was just confirming what you said, with minor suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your way is good. but when we are not showing that value on form then there is no need to match hidden field with session value. Do your calculation according to session variable value if someone edit hidden field value that does not effect your calculation..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even storing the price in the form? That should be stored server-side only. You can *display* the price to the user, but you don't need to have them submit it back to you.

Comment: The price is being submitted to an external payment gateway, I think you have misread my question.

Comment: @Kyle: Oh....where in your question did you say that? If it's PayPal, they actually do have options for encrypting your form.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough for me:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// thanks to bantam
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#87526
define('SALT', 'whateveryouwant'); // use define, db stored value, var, included, etc.
function encrypt($text)
{
  return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}

function decrypt($text) 
{ 
  return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}

unset($_SESSION['baskettotal']);
unset($_SESSION['basketids']);

$grand = 350;
$ids = array(1, 3, 5);

$_SESSION['baskettotal'] = $grand;
$_SESSION['basketids'] = implode(", ", $ids);

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
  <input type="hidden" name="enc" value="<?= encrypt('stackoverflow' . $_SESSION['baskettotal'] . $_SESSION['basketids'] );?>" />
  <input name="send" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?
if ( decrypt($_POST['enc']) !== 'stackoverflow' . $_SESSION['baskettotal'] . $_SESSION['basketids'] ) die('Not so fast');
else echo 'Go ahead';
?>
```

On first run you obtain:

*Not so fast*

When you click on submit button:

*Go ahead*

Hope it helps. [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#87526)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code was okay, while further "improvement" makes not much sense.
I see no use for all that hidden hashes stuff.

Why not to just make it

```
$_SESSION['baskettotal'] = $grand;
$_SESSION['basketids'] = $ids;
```

and then get these 2 variables from the session upon POST submit.

```
$grand = $_SESSION['baskettotal'];
$ids   = $_SESSION['basketids'];
```

That's ALL!
Why devise all that stuff, unnecessary complicating your code?

Answer (score -1):

If the form is being submitted to an external script. Then your session checks will be useless since you do not do the final data checking.

To be completely secure(or at least a semblance of it) store the prices server side with the IDs in a session, then on checkout, use curl to perform the external call after your final checks.

Comment: I've already written the script to handle that, I wasn't asking about this, I was asking for the most secure way to pass some information through a post without the use of sending them through hidden form fields which can be easily manipulated. It seems my way was best. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I only mentioned this because you said in another comment that you were submitting it to an external script. 
If you read closely,  apart from the curl part, the methods are mainly the same.
Hope you solved it though.h.